# How to install ChartJS on local machine?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

I'm creating charts with chartjs using cdn version, but I want to install it in my website. I've downloaded ChartJS v4.1.1, but it has only typescript files. But, i can't use TS files in website. It should be JavaScript files, So now what should I do.

sorry for no code, If you know then please answer. I haven't found it on google yet.
Thank You

Comment: Something's not clear here. If you want to use Chart.js in your web site just load it from the CDN. The whole point of the CDN is that you don't need your own copy.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find chart.js in the package.
Or download it from (for example) https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js